# Linux Console System info program like linfo

Tags: command-line

There is a nice program written in php5 that displays
a lot of system info on the running system.

Visit:     http://linfo.sourceforge.net/

Is there a comparable tool that runs in a linux console
and displays the info directly on screen?

I know about lshw or lspci but that is not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at `hardinfo` -

> HardInfo can gather information about your system's hardware and
>   operating system, perform benchmarks, and generate printable reports
>   either in HTML or in plain text formats. HardInfo performs CPU and FPU
>   benchmarks and has a very clean GTK-based interface.

[image]

To install : `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

Comment: Is there something similar that runs in a console?

Comment: @TonyMartin `hardinfo` has a command-line interfaced as `hardinfo`. For more information, see:

`hardinfo --help`